# Simplifying a boolean algebra equation (A'B + AC + ABC' + BC)

Tags: boolean-algebra

$A'B + AC + ABC' + BC$

$A'B+AC+ABC'$ (Complement's theorem)

Could I get a hint of where to proceed next? I've been going back and forth looking at theorems but can't understand how one would fit with all the different variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the ABC' to AB because ABC is part of AC, like this:

$A'B + AC + ABC' + BC = A'B + AC + ABC' = A'B + ABC + AB'C + ABC' = A'B + ABC + AB'C + ABC + ABC' = A'B + AC + AB = B + AC$